# Creating graphic using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, graphics

I'm working with ArcGIS Desktop 10 and I have different polygon features in different layers with their attributes like shape_area. I would like to create a unique graphic where it is possible to see the respective percentage of each one.

Can I do this if I have different layers?

Comment: Percentage of what? Percentage of overall coverage? Can you expound a bit? With different layers it can be accomplished "with some finesse". The easy way is to combine into one layer, however you will need to calculate the percentage to a field.

Comment: I'm sorry, yes the percentage of overall coverage. I have different layers with sediment, live corals, dead corals etc etc. I would like to know how many is the percentage for each one respect the total area.

Comment: Try to edit the question title. it is a bit un-inviting.

Comment: In which context do you mean Graphic, a [Silverlight graphic](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/apiref/api_start.htm), or a [desktop graphic](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IGraphicElement_Interface/00120000058m000000/)?

Comment: Are you looking to create something like a pie chart for insertion into a report?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps just combine them all once to get a total area to use for your calculations.
Then you would need to have a field in each layer for the percentage.
Run the calculation.
Create a classification for one layer with the min max, and define specific breaks. 
Maybe 5 classes.
Create an lyr (layer) file for the first one and apply it to each subsequently.
This would depend on you using the same field name for calculating the percentage in each layer.

I may be wrong but it seems that you might want to sum all the areas of one layer and show that percentage as a class.